# Why does this code return undefined method 'length' for nil::NilClass?

Tags: ruby, block

My method is supposed to accept a block and use it for comparing two elements in sorting. It work like:

```
bubble_sort_by(["hi","hello","hey"]) do |left,right|
  left.length - right.length
end
# => ["hi", "hey", "hello"]
```

This is my method:

```
def bubble_sort_by (arr)
  i = 1
  until i == arr.length
    if yield > 0
      x = arr[i]
      arr[i] = arr[i-1]
      arr[i-1] = x
      i -= 1
      p arr #Check State
    else i += 1
      p arr #Check state
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

I don't understand why it's not working. It works when I compare the elements of the array without using a block. I just swapped the index-based comparison with the yield to modify it for a block. I suppose it's going out of bounds of the array and returning a `nil`. Can somebody show me where the code breaks?

Comment: I print the state of the array to visualize the sorting

Comment: Please show how you're using this, including the input array and the block, and what output you expect.

Comment: And the error message as shown.

Comment: I actually just copy and pasted it wrong, I had two methods. I'll edit the OP to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're receiving `undefined method 'length' for nil:NilClass` because your function does not pass any parameters to `yield`. Instead, the `yield` statement is trying to evaluate the block on nil parameters, giving you an error from `left.length`.

This is what I got when I ran your code in `irb`:

```
irb(main):001:0> require './ex.rb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> bubble_sort_by(["hi","hello","hey"]) do |left,right|
irb(main):003:1*   left.length - right.length
irb(main):004:1> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):3:in `block in irb_binding'
    from /Users/amar/Downloads/ex.rb:4:in `bubble_sort_by'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/amar/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I edited your `if` condition to fix the `yield`:

```
if (yield arr[i-1], arr[i]) > 0
```

And I got this output, which I believe is what you wanted:

```
irb(main):001:0> require './ex.rb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> bubble_sort_by(["hi","hello","hey"]) do |left,right|
irb(main):003:1*   left.length - right.length
irb(main):004:1> end
["hi", "hello", "hey"]
["hi", "hey", "hello"]
["hi", "hey", "hello"]
["hi", "hey", "hello"]
=> ["hi", "hey", "hello"]
```

So, to sum up, remember to pass your arguments when using `yield`. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the nil error because left and right are both nil.

The reason is because you are yielding a block that takes two arguments, but you are not supplying those arguments via your yield statement.

Your hypothesis is off base, your error is not because of being out of bounds of the array.  Though that happens if you avoid the error.